# ScaleAnimation to enlarge a bar bottom up

Tags: android, animation

I want enlarge a bar, which should display voting results. I use simple coloured views for that, placed in a RelativeLayout.

```xml
<View
    android:id="@+id/q1"
    android:layout_width="81dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="189dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="129dp"
    android:background="@color/cdu" />
```

The code which should animate the bar is:

```java
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 1f, 0f, -1f, -1f, 1f);
anim.setDuration(2000);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
v.startAnimation(anim);
```

The animation works so far, but it is in the wrong direction, it grows from top down. I have played a lot of hours with the options and STFW for that simple thing. Without success.

Thanks for all hints and offers to fix the problem for money.
Daniel